# Why is the title page running over the end of the document?

Tags: formatting, latex

I am attempting to create a paper with the elsarticle.cls class, and have it be 2 columns.  There are O(100) authors on the paper.  For some reason, the author list spills over the bottom margin rather than continuing onto the next page, so the abstract never appears in the document.  Below is a minimal working example of this type of problem.

```
\documentclass[english,10pt,final,twocolumn]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multido}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}{}

\title{
A minimal working example of an author list erroniously going beyond the bottom of a page in an 2-column Elsevier article.
}

\newcommand*{\UCR}{University of California Riverside, 900 University Avenue, Riverside, CA 92521, USA}
\newcommand*{\UCRindex}{39}
%Here I give myself 1000 times authorship on this paper just to fill up the page
\multido{}{1000}{ \author[toUCR]{S.J.~Paul}}
 \address[toUCR]{\UCR} 


\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[3]
\end{abstract}
%\date{\today}
\end{frontmatter}{}
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

This produces the file shown below.  How do I fix this?

[Rendered document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umi2C.png)

Comment: Instead of the `twocolumn` class option, you could leave the front matter single columned and switch to `\twocolumn` after the frontmatter

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you could remove the `twocolumn` class option and manually switch to two column layout after the frontmatter:

```
\documentclass[english,10pt,final,
%twocolumn
]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
%\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{multido}

\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}{}

\title{
A minimal working example of an author list erroniously going beyond the bottom of a page in an 2-column Elsevier article.
}

\newcommand*{\UCR}{University of California Riverside, 900 University Avenue, Riverside, CA 92521, USA}
\newcommand*{\UCRindex}{39}
%Here I give myself 1000 times authorship on this paper just to fill up the page
\multido{}{1000}{ \author[toUCR]{S.J.~Paul}}
 \address[toUCR]{\UCR} 


\begin{abstract}
\lipsum[3]
\end{abstract}
%\date{\today}
\end{frontmatter}
\twocolumn
\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```